# Why is the subject singular in this sentence (ponies are a breed that need to be protected)

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

From [this BBC News article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-north-west-wales-22304043):

> The wild Carneddau ponies of Snowdonia are a unique breed that need to be protected, say scientists

I was surprised to read *need*, expecting *needs*.

Why does it say *a breed that* ***need*** *to be protected*, and not *a breed that* ***needs*** *to be protected*?

In this sentence, I think *that* refers to *breed*, not to *ponies*.
I'm aware that with British English [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) rules, sport teams, companies, and probably some other groups, [may get a plural verb even if they appear singular](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/21009) (*Arsenal rule*, *BP have made profits*, etc.).  Does this apply to *breed*?  Or is there a different reason why the verb in the cited sentence is a plural one?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be British English rather than American English, but it doesn't jar me at all.

I'd just rewrite the sentence as

> *The wild Carneddau ponies of Snowdonia are **a unique breed needing protection**, say scientists.*

Otherwise, in American English, you're right: it would have to be:

> ***a breed that needs** protection.*